# Spring-data-elasticsearch @CompletionField does not create field with type "complete"

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using `Spring-data-elasticsearch` and there `ElasticsearchTemplate` functions.

I try to create an index by using the `@CompletionField` annotation on a `Completion` field named `suggest`.

```
@Document(indexName = "city", type = "city")
public class City {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String name;

    @CompletionField
    private Completion suggest;
}
```

The `@CompletionField` annotation should be used to for the suggest-complete functions of elasticsearch. Like described in the java-doc:

```
/**
 * Based on the reference doc - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html
 *
 * @author Mewes Kochheim
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface CompletionField {
```

In the [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters-completion.html#completion-suggester-mapping) they say, that the field should have a type `complete` to use the suggest-complete functions.

**But if I create my index unfortunately the field `suggest` has not the type `complete` instead it hast the type `keyword`. Which gives me an error when I try to query a suggest query.**

```
CompletionSuggestionBuilder s = SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion("suggest").prefix(text, Fuzziness.ONE);
SuggestBuilder b = new SuggestBuilder().addSuggestion("test-suggest", s);
SearchResponse response = elasticsearchTemplate.suggest(b, "city");
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no mapping found for field [suggest]
```

All my code is based on the spring-data-elasticsearch git repository.

[ElasticsearchTemplateCompletionTests.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/completion/ElasticsearchTemplateCompletionTests.java)

[CompletionAnnotatedEntity.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/completion/CompletionAnnotatedEntity.java)

Do I miss any configuration in my `City` document or any other annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't set up a Repository for this entity, like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface CityRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<City, String> {

}
```